# My server is being DOS'ed

Tags: windows-server-2008

I currently have 7 applications running on port 2101, 2102 and so forth that are being attacked. Any idea on how I can resolve the matters other than banning the IP?

Those applications are supposed to accept connections from clients, but in this case it seems like the attacker is just using an application to connect to the port and act as if its the actual client.

Thanks for any suggestions.

Comment: Ban the offending IPs, or check on ways to limit the number of connection attempts per unit time from a given IP.

Comment: They are using dynamic IP. When I ban it they just restart their routers and get a new IP.

Comment: If you use something like Linux' `fail2ban` they get blocked automatically after a few attempts, it should at least help in riding out the wave.

Comment: I'm on windows though.

Comment: I know. But I'm assuming there is something similar out there for you poor souls...

Comment: The first question you have to answer is this: How is the attack hurting you? Is it maxing out your CPU? Is it maxing out your inbound bandwidth? Is it maxing out your inbound bandwidth? Is it running you out of connection slots or some application resource? Or what?

Comment: Its maxing out the RAM. because of too many connections.

Comment: What, if anything, is sitting between the server and the internet?

Answer (score 2):

First you actually firewall off the attacker's IP address. If you didn't do that already, there's no point in discussing anything else.

Second, you can [look up the owner of the IP address](http://whois.arin.net/) and contact the attacker's ISP via their `abuse` email address. Be prepared to provide firewall logs and other logs of their malicious activity.

Comment: I have blocked it but they just keep changing their IP.
  
And My ISP doesn't really care.

Comment: I didn't say anything about contacting _your_ ISP.

Comment: I mean, we have the same ISP though. :)

Comment: I'm running my server from a company offshore. I remote it. The attacker is from the same country I'm from so my home net and his are the same ISP. that isp doesn't care. I have told my server provider but they cant help.